# Restarting level in Super Meat Boy

Tags: super-meat-boy

Is there a key to restart a level in Super Meat Boy?

Other than going back to level select and selecting it again, I mean.

(I'm playing it on OSX/Steam, in case this matters)

Comment: What do you mean by 'restarting'? Why don't you just kill yourself?

Comment: @ver: you can't in earlier levels where there aren't so many things able to kill you. However, since later on they are pretty much everywhere, I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Oh, yes, killing yourself _in game_ is _exactly_ what I meant. :D  (Now that I read what I wrote before, it sounds kinda funny. :D )

Comment: @ver rofl I didn't notice, gg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no restart in Super Meat Boy other than killing yourself, or even finishing the level which will prompt you if you want to re-try the level.  With how fast the game can load, however, this is almost as quick, if not, faster than any other game's restart.

Comment: Really? I always have tremendous difficulties dying in SMB.

Comment: @StevenJeuris yeah, it's really over the top. Sometimes you have to trudge for fifteen minutes through five levels, 'til you finally find something that can kill you.

Comment: I'm currently watching my friend play.  He finally finished part 1 of Dr Fetus where he chases you.  During the escape portion, he somehow got glitched through the wall and stuck in a place with no death traps.  Because of this, he has to restart the whole Dr Fetus level over again.  Lame.  A suicide option would have allowed him to restart only the escape portion.

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the level by choosing a new character. For example if you're playing as meat boy, switch character to Commander Video and the level resets.

I'm not sure if it does this when switching from one character to the same, i.e. meat boy to meat boy.